# How to create baked bread shader?

Tags: materials, shaders

I want to make a bread shader so that it is darker on top than on the bottom. I know how to make color, bumps and everything else, I'm only interested in a black and white mask for mixing colors. Of course, I can use the usual gradient texture, but I want this transition to be less direct. So far, I'm not doing very well. I hope that I clearly wrote, you can see in the picture what I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is version without bumping, only simple mask

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here, try this setup:

[image: BreadShaderExample]

The "mask factor" you are looking for, I achieved by rotating (and slightly moving) a *Gradient Texture*, and controlling it's cutoffs with a *ColorRamp*. I then used it as a mix factor for the "bread colors" and adjusted the *ColorRamp* until it looked right. (This works very well to control the darkness levels).

[image: GradientControl]

I then mixed a *Noise Texture* and a *Musgrave Texture* to give a scattered displacement pattern, and I used it's inverse as a roughness factor.

[image: Displacement]

I thought the bread colors looked too plain, so I combined yet another *Musgrave Texture* with a couple of *Noise Textures* and multiplied them with the bread colors to transfer the darks only.

[image: AddedDarks]

Lastly, I added the whites from a clamped, detailed musgrave texture to get the "flour coating" on the crust of the bread.

[image: FlourCoat]

I'll also upload the .blend in case you want to play with it. I even threw in a couple of extra procedural textures (The pan and the table) that can be used as examples.

[image: FinalProduct]

File is here - [image]

Happy shading!

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try using a gradient on the Z axis controlled using a color ramp, like this. Not sure if this works with your workflow and the final result you're hoping to achieve, but I hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: No, I want the top to be completely painted over, and there should be bumps around the edges

Comment: @user Sorry I wasn't able to be more help! Good luck though!